# How do people carry things in Star Trek TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, costume, star-trek-uniforms, props

In cast interviews, I remember a montage of everyone saying "pockets". The uniforms don't have them.

On away missions, I think Crusher put her tricorder "away" on occasion, and other than someone who will be operating a single instrument for the duration (so no need to put it down), personnel will general have several items, such as the ubiquitous tricorder, some geology tools, local currency if applicable, collected samples; not to mention tissues, water, and snacks.  Flashlights were in-hand if exploring a cave, but where were they stowed otherwise?

In addition, the com badges might actually be general purpose machines (or at least act as a thin terminal to a computer brought down with the group), they don't have displays like my smartphone.

In-universe, they don't need ID and paperwork other than their badges... but if on a civilized non-federation world or nation therof, maybe they do need to carry ID and permits.

I seem to recall phasers having a belt holster of some kind but it's not conspicuous enough that I remember any fashion about it.

So, are there any recolections or screen grabs of packs, messenger bags, utility belts, etc.?  At ComicCon fanexpo (Dallas), I want to prepare something that is *practical* for actual use, has canon precedent (preferred), or at least looks like it belongs.

---

My current idea is to use a [modular belt system](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/hands-reviews/belt-systems-camera-slingers) as sold for photograpy.
[image]

There is some overlap between the "camera bag" kit at military kit, with some kind of standard velcro mounting from the latter making inroads in the former.  But light-duity and black nylon is typical of camera belt-bags, and I can use stuff with more conventional outings as well, justifying more budget.

Some kind of mods to make it look more in-universe, and changing the branding into livery...?

(I do in fact want to carry a good camera, so need pack space for that)

Or is there some other type of satchel, messenger bag, or whatnot that is a better idea?

Comment: I seem to remember fitted pouches for things like phasers and tricorders appearing like magic when they were needed

Comment: I don't have the dvd set (I'm a TOS fan normally) so screen grabs or any notes on how such narrative-imparative pouches were fastened to the crewmember?

Comment: I just imagine that someone at the Daystrom Institute has invented a Bag of Holding based on a modified portable transporter/replicator that stores items in a pattern buffer and simply materializes them when they're needed.

Comment: That would be a great episode, where Murdock (I still think *traaaash bag!*) gets his geek on with a prototype and things don't quite work right. Taking it *through* a transporter itself is not a good idea.  Consternation atnthe console, "it looks like the pattern buffer is overflowing like we exceeded the transport capacity, but he's just one guy! More power!" And he materializes under a huge mound of junk, released from holding.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté This is actually exactly how it works in some of the Star Trek games (e.g. Voyager: Elite Force).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Pockets and Pouches

There's no evidence that Starfleet uniforms in TNG have pockets. Generally speaking, handheld equipment for away missions (phasers, tricorders) was stowed in fitted pouches. The below screenshot (from the episode ["Timescape"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Timescape_(episode)), shows them from a bunch of angles:

[image: Mucho des pouches]

It's a little hard to see (likely by design), but the pouches and uniform seem to be separate components of a modular belt system much like the one shown in the question; they seem to be attached to the uniform's hip with Space-velcro.

However, some outwear appears to have pockets; [Ellesedil points out in comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86827/how-do-people-carry-things-in-star-trek-tng/86829#comment190230_86829) that Doctor Crusher's labcoat is sometimes shown to have pockets, as in this screenshot from ["The Inner Light"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(episode)):

[image: Crusher's labcoat with pockets]

Similarly, B'Elanna Torres often wore an overcoat with a breast pocket in *Voyager*'s later seasons, where she would store small hand tools:

[image: The magical pregnancy concealing overcoat]

### Hand-held cases

We occasionally see redshirts<sup>1</sup> carrying scientific equipment in large crates, for example, but we also sometimes see Doctor Crusher with a portable medical kit (from ["Skin of Evil"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)):

[image: Crusher and her purse]

Later variants of the medkit may be more amenable to conning. The two pictured below are from *Voyager* (["The Gift"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Gift_(episode))) rather than TNG, but it's all the same era in the *Trek* universe:

[image: Medkit varieties]

Since I've broken from TNG anyway, O'Brien's toolbox from DS9 is also worth a mention:

[image: O'Brien's tools]

### Backpacks

[Thomas W. points out in comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86827/how-do-people-carry-things-in-star-trek-tng/86829#comment190284_86829) that there's precedent for backpacks in the *Star Trek* universe, as seen on DS9 (thanks to [Mr. Bultitude](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86827/how-do-people-carry-things-in-star-trek-tng/86829#comment190325_86829) for the picture):

[image: Backpacks]

However, I'm not sure how far they'd fit into a Starfleet costume. Your mileage may vary.

In the realm of over-the-shoulder bags, I haven't been able to find any screenshots from episodes. However, a [24th century carry case prop](http://startrekauction.blogspot.ca/2007_07_01_archive.html) was sold in an *It's a Wrap* auction in 2007:

[image: Case with strap]

So we still have shoulder straps in the future. Which is nice.

---

<sup>1</sup> Are they still redshirts in TNG, or do we have to call them goldshirts?

Comment: Beverly Crusher's lab coat eventually has pockets in it. She often puts her tricorder away in it. See [here](http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120205210316/memoryalpha/en/images/d/d4/Crusher_medtricorder.jpg) where the pocket is clearly visible at the bottom-right of the picture. Not sure what season the pockets started appearing in.

Comment: @Ellesedil That's a good catch, thanks! Added it to the answer

Comment: Don't forget the supply backpacks which Capt. Sisko, Ezri Dax, Jake Sisko, and Mister Sisko (Capt. Sisko's dad) had when they went to Tyree to recover the Orb of the Emissary in DS9 - they kept backpacks with water/supplies but they also had a small shovel in there if memory serves me right.  Stands to reason utility equipment might be carried separately as a back worn pack, such as modern military may carry (or like was seen in the episode I referenced).  Not as useful per the OP's general idea, but valid enough to point out as well.

Comment: @JasonBaker At least one does not die every episode, so they aren't redshirts. It has nothing to do with shirt color

Comment: @ThomasW. That's a very good point. Do you happen to have a screenshot? I'm having trouble locating one

Comment: None of these are very good, but the backpacks are there: http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/epics/DS9552.jpg http://www.yourprops.com/movieprops/default/yp52d60c423477c0.48138552/Star-Trek-Deep-Space-Nine-Jake-Sisko-Desert-Robe-Shirt-4.jpg http://dominion.tvheaven.com/edit7.html The episode is Shadows and Symbols.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Thanks for the finds!

Answer (score 12):

This was the first thing that popped into my head, and Jason Baker's otherwise comprehensive answer missed it.  When crew members were going on shore leave, personal items were frequently carried in rather silly cylindrical hard-shell cases:

[image: TNG duffel cases]

I don't know how practical you consider this for carrying around a con.  It doesn't look very comfortable.

Comment: @JasonBaker I don't recall.  My wife and I watched the entire series on streaming last year, and we commented on the absurdity of those bags every time they appeared.  I think I remember Picard taking one to Risa at some point, dressed to the nines and carrying that stupid thing.

Comment: @JasonBaker TNG 1x15, [11001001](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/11001001_(episode)) - those are padded uniforms for [parrises squares](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Parrises_squares), and the cylinder appears to be more like a gym bag than general use...  I don't recall them being used other times.  (Worf:  "If winning is not important, then Commander, why keep score?")

Comment: Data uses the same one to pack up his personal belongs in 2x9 The Measure of a Man

Comment: I note this: one-off "find a prop for this" can be dressed by using appropriate labels. If they grabbed standard general-purpose containers from storage, they would have the ship's ID. Perhaps that is so people buying stuff on *away* can leave containers at and they find their way to the right ship.

Comment: ro laren used one of these as well when she came aboard enterprise http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pNj1i7V1f7s/VDmjXtfwgOI/AAAAAAAA1z8/pEjfPoa5ChI/s1600/ensign-ro-hd-052.jpg