# Which Starfleet uniforms have pockets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-uniforms

Which Starfleet uniforms have pockets? And where are the pockets?

Comment: The only built-in pocket I remember is b'elanna Torres who had an engineer's labcoat (to cover her RL pregnancy) which had a top pocket.

Everyone else seemed to use pouches which attached magically to their uniforms.  Exception was TOS, when sciencey types had leather pouches with straps.

Comment: Addendum: http://voy.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/4x14/messageinabottle_009.jpg

Comment: All of Star _Trek_ or only Star _fleet_?

Comment: Enterprise era uniforms have [lots and lots of pockets](http://www.startrek.com/imageuploads/200309/reed-publicity-03-02/240x320.jpg)

Comment: Star Fleet? Didn't realize there was a distinction.

Comment: "Star Trek" would include all of the of all of the various species throughout the history of the franchise (which number in the hundreds). "Starfleet" would limit the question to the uniforms worn by officers serving within that organization.

Comment: Beverly Crusher's lab coat has pockets I think.

Comment: Related question from the TNG era: [How do people carry things in Star Trek TNG?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86827/how-do-people-carry-things-in-star-trek-tng)

Comment: Only the men's. >:-|

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within Starfleet, there are a few example of uniforms with pockets:

Enterprise-era jumpsuits contained a lot of pockets, suiting the utilitarian nature of Starfleet uniforms during this era.

[image: Enterpise uniform]

The Next Generation TV era: Pockets are sparse in this era, though Beverly Crusher has a lab coat with pockets.

[image: Beverly Crusher with lab coat]

Voyager: Belanna Torres used, for most of season 4, an "engineering jacket" with a breast pocket. Out of universe, the reason for this was to hide the actress' pregnancy.

[image: Engineering Jacket]

It is also likely that the uniforms seen in 'The Search for Spock' and 'The Voyage Home' also contain at least one hidden pocket inside, since whilst incognito in San Francisco communicators and phasers are carried without being seen outside the uniform.

[image: The Voyage Home uniform]

These, however, seem to be exceptions from the norm. Rather than obvious pockets, most Starfleet personnel usually use pouches, attached to the hip, when required to hold equipment and holster phasers etc based on the requirements of the task.

Comment: Many of the outfits in ST3 & ST4 were not uniforms at all.

Comment: @T.J.L. Uhura and Scotty are still wearing proper Starfleet uniform.

Comment: @T.J.L. I chose 'The Voyage Home' as this is an example where something is covertly carried, as per the question. You're well within your rights to downvote if you feel my answer in inaccurate and write a better one, that's what this site is for after all. Have a nice day.

Comment: Comments are to provide suggestions for people to make an answer better, too. If you want to use ST4 as an example, focus on the *one* person who wore a uniform, there were no uniform*s* (plural).

Comment: @T.J.L. I would argue that Scotty's jacket is, in fact, official uniform based on other sightings in "The Search for Spock" and "The Final Frontier". It is also seen worn by other characters. see http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_%28late_2270s-2350s%29#Bomber_jacket

Answer (score 7):

### Star Trek: Discovery

The uniforms from *Star Trek: Discovery* have two pockets on the trousers, closed by two zippers

[image]

### Abramsverse

The reboot movies feature some uniforms whose jackets have zipped pockets:

[image]